# Using column specific value from a list of values within an apply function

Tags: r, vectorization

I am writing my own normalization function for scRNA-seq data as many packages assume you are working with densematrices (which I do not want to nor need to do).  If you don't know what that means its not an issue.  Essentially I want to be able to have a supply function devide all values in a column by a value specific to that column.  SO to that end I supply a list of values of the same length as the columns of the data frame.  Then other transformations are applied, if no list is provided a sum of the values in the column apply is working on is used instead.  Is there a way to do this without a for loop, to keep it vectorized?

```
# function to run in apply
pseudocount_log2p1_transform <- function(x, scale_factor = 10000, UMI.provided = NULL){
  if(is.null(UMI.provided)){
    counts <- sum(x)}else{
      counts <- UMI.provided
    }
  x <- (x+1)/counts
  x <- x/scale_factor
  return(log2(x))
}

# function which needs fixing
pavlab.normalize <- function(df, UMI = NULL){
  df.cols <- colnames(df)
  df.rows <- rownames(df)
  if( is.null(UMI)){
    df <- data.frame(apply(df,  MARGIN = 2, pseudocount_log2p1_transform))
  }else{
# this line needs to be modified, so its providing the column specific count value
    df <- data.frame(apply(df,  MARGIN = 2, pseudocount_log2p1_transform(UMI.provided=UMI)))
  }
  colnames(df) <- df.cols
  rownames(df)<- df.rows
  return(df)
}

# reproducible example
df.example <- data.frame( a = c(1,0,1,2),
b = c(5,6,8,5),
c = c(4, 5, 4,4) )

count.list <- c(5, 25, 18)

# how do I fix this....?
pavlab.normalize(df = df.example, UMI = count.list)
```

Comment: I guess the modification would be `df[] <- Map(pseudocount_log2p1_transform, df, UMI.provided = UMI)`

Comment: Could you kindly please provide this as an answer so I can vote for it and close the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code, if we want to apply corresponding values of UMI with the corresponding columns, instead of using `apply` which loop over the columns of 'df' only we can use `Map` with input arguments as `df` and the `UMI` and thus it loops over the columns in the data.frame  and the elements in the vector assuming the `ncol(df)` and `length(UMI)` are the same

```
pavlab.normalize <- function(df, UMI = NULL){
  df.cols <- colnames(df)
  df.rows <- rownames(df)
  if( is.null(UMI)){
    df <- data.frame(apply(df,  MARGIN = 2, pseudocount_log2p1_transform))
  }else{
#
   df[] <- Map(pseudocount_log2p1_transform, df, UMI.provided = UMI)
  
  }
  colnames(df) <- df.cols
  rownames(df)<- df.rows
  return(df)
}
```

-testing

```
> pavlab.normalize(df = df.example, UMI = count.list)
          a         b         c
1 -14.60964 -15.34661 -15.13571
2 -15.60964 -15.12421 -14.87267
3 -14.60964 -14.76164 -15.13571
4 -14.02468 -15.34661 -15.13571
```